# Is there limit to create ling-aggregation on FreeBSD 10 by default?

Tags: freebsd, bonding

I'm new using FreeBSD and one of the things that we need is two link aggregation interfaces. Looking for on Internet I found out that we can put the configuration on `/etc/rc.conf`. I tried to config my two interfaces but just one been up.

Here my `rc.conf`:

```
hostname="freebsd-t1"
sshd_enable="YES"
# Set dumpdev to "AUTO" to enable crash dumps, "NO" to disable
dumpdev="AUTO"
# 
# Enable LACP aggregation -> team0
ifconfig_em2="up"
ifconfig_em2="-lro -tso"
cloned_interfaces="lagg0"
ifconfig_lagg0_name="team0"
ifconfig_team0="laggproto lacp laggport em2"
#
# Enable LACP aggregation -> team1
ifconfig_em0="up"
ifconfig_em1="up"
ifconfig_em0="-lro -tso"
ifconfig_em1="-lro -tso"
cloned_interfaces="lagg1"
ifconfig_lagg1_name="team1"
ifconfig_team1="laggproto lacp laggport em0 laggport em1"
#
```

The link-aggregation team1 works fine but I nothing about team0. Is there any limit to create link aggregation by default?

Any one pass through this problem?

Just a note: If I try to run all commands on terminal all works fine.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of your `rc.conf` file is wrong. It is a [sh(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh) source file. When you set the same variable for a second time, it replaces the previous value. So you need to make all of your values a *space separated* list.

Try this:

```
hostname="freebsd-t1"
sshd_enable="YES"
# Set dumpdev to "AUTO" to enable crash dumps, "NO" to disable
dumpdev="AUTO"

cloned_interfaces="lagg0 lagg1"

# Enable LACP aggregation -> team0
ifconfig_em2="-lro -tso up"
ifconfig_lagg0_name="team0"
ifconfig_team0="laggproto lacp laggport em2"

# Enable LACP aggregation -> team1
ifconfig_em0="-lro -tso up"
ifconfig_em1="-lro -tso up"
ifconfig_lagg1_name="team1"
ifconfig_team1="laggproto lacp laggport em0 laggport em1"
```

Comment: Hello Richard. Very thank for you answer. Know is working fine, just like you putted there.

Best regards.